Bounding sum of these binomial coefficients
I need to find an upper bound for $$\binom{n^2}{cn} + \binom{n^2}{cn-1} + \dots + \binom{n^2}{0}$$
where $c$ is a constant. Obviously, one upper bound is $\binom{n^2}{n^2} + \dots + \binom{n^2}{0} = 2^{n^2}$ but this is too loose. I tried to do some manipulations with common identities, which didn't work. Also, I looked at some MathOverflow posts, but all of them resolve problems like finding an upper bound for $\binom{n^2}{k} + \dots + \binom{n^2}{0}$ where $k$ is fixed and $n$ is the only variable, which is not the case for my problem.
Any help would be appreciated – thanks!

You'd have to be more specific about how loose the upper bound can be.  EG $cn { n^2 \choose cn}$ is an obvious upper bound, as is $ (cn-1) { n^2 \choose cn } + 1 $, but I'm guessing that neither are that helpful for you.

@CalvinLin If this can be exponentially bounded (instead of double exponential like $2^{n^2}$), that would be great.

What kind of bound are you looking for? Notice that $\binom{n^2}{cn}$ is the dominating term, and we can prove that $\binom{n^2}{cn-k}$ is at most $(\frac{c}{n})^k$ times $\binom{n^2}{cn}$ which implies the sum is at most $\frac{n}{n-c}$ times the dominated term, so we can just bound $\binom{n^2}{cn}$, which equals to
$$\binom{n^2}{0}+\dots+\binom{n^2}{cn}\approx\binom{n^2}{cn}=\frac{n^2(n^2-1)\dots (n^2-cn+1)}{(cn)!}\approx\frac{n^{2cn}}{(cn)!}e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}}$$
And this ratio for these two $\approx$'s goes to $1$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

... Also, $(cn)!$ up there you can do it by Stirling's Formula.
